# Should this be an INNER JOIN or LEFT Join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

My goal is to select the list of cats and amazon birds, with their sex, their speecie (latin name) and their race (if it exists) and group the cats together, and the amazong birds together, and inside of their speecie, groupe the race together.

I first failed to have the right query but then I saw the solution and don't understand it very well.

So here's the solution :

```
SELECT Animal.nom as nom_animal, Animal.sexe, Espece.nom_latin as espece, Race.nom as race
FROM Animal
 INNER JOIN Specie
    ON Animal.specie_id = Specie.id
LEFT JOIN Race
    ON Animal.race_id = Race.id
WHERE Specie.nom_courant IN ('Amazon birds', 'Cat')
ORDER BY Specie.nom_latin, Race.nom;
```

Why this can't be :

```
FROM Animal
 INNER JOIN Specie
    ON Animal.specie_id = Specie.id
INNER JOIN JOIN Race
    ON Animal.race_id = Race.id
WHERE Specie.nom_courant IN ('Amazon birds', 'Cat')
GROUP BY Specie.nom_latin, Race.nom;
```

Because as I understood : I only have to select Animal when it's available

Also what is the practicl use of GROUP BY and ORDER BY and how to know which one to use and when ?

The query has been copied from a french source.

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. What does "group together" mean? Explain what the output should look like in terms of the input. What does " I only have to select Animal when it's available" mean? Also please read & act on [mcve]. That includes constraints on your tables, which might make expressions that can in general give different results give the same result. Please read & act on [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.  Re group by & order by, don't ask questions that are already answered or ask for chapters of textbooks/documentation--read them.

Comment: PS If you would like some other opinions/guidance you could ask at [meta]. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the way the database is created and the data is stored.

**If all animals had race** then it would not matter -- at all. But it seems it's not the case of your example.

It seems that for some animals the `Animal.race_id` is null. When that happens, do you want to show the animal anyway with an *empty* race?

- If so, use `LEFT JOIN`: shows all the animals, regardless they have or not race.
- Otherwise, use `INNER JOIN`: shows all the animals with their race; if an animal does not have a race, it's not shown.

**Second question: ORDER BY vs GROUP BY**

These two are quite different:

- [**ORDER BY**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) sorts the returned rows so they are shown in a particular order.
- [**GROUP BY**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) would do something totally different. It will show probably less rows: one row per species/race combination only. So two cats will be shown as a single row; probably you don't want this. It's useful to get totals and subtotals.

Comment: All we actually know is, the left join differs from the inner when/iff not every Animal-join-Species Animal.race_ids equals a Race id. That might be because race_ids are null or are non-null but aren't Race ids. So "It seems that for some animals the Animal.race_id is null" is not justified. (And  "If all animals had race" is unclear.) Your answer is *one* way the joins could differ. And you don't give your assumptions. And anyway you should not assume, but ask for all relevant info. (Here, constraints.) We don't even know whether the left join *is* actually necessary.

Comment: Much appreciated! Now I understand. Please pardon the lack of clarifications.
So do you confirm that in order to build a query I must first get a description of the database tables in hand then check how it is made internally and what does the values mean in proportion to my desired results. 
I'd love to know how to be certainly sure that my result is correct (I heard people get fired because of this)

Comment: In an ideal world you would have a good documentation of the database you are using (aka a "data dictionary"). More often than not, there's nothing, or is severily outdated. You would need to look at the table & column definitions to find out if they accept null values, their type, their primary and foreign key definitions, etc. That's the real world, unfortunately.